# How do I dual boot Ubuntu and Kali on one external hard drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, external-hdd

More specifically, how do I get it to work?

I have install Ubuntu on my external hard drive, and it works flawlessly, with Grub2 appearing and I have the option between Ubuntu and Kali, however kali does not work.

When I select Kali, it says `attempt to read outside disk hd0.` Then I have to reboot as all the other operating systems say that too.

Details:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

/dev/sda1  *         2048    208895    206848   101M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT<br>
/dev/sda2          208896 347426815 347217920 165.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT<br>
/dev/sda3       347426816 351649839   4223024     2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000170586112 bytes, 1953458176 sectors<br>
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes<br>
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes<br>
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes<br>
Disklabel type: dos<br>
Disk identifier: 0x263a01fb<br>

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type<br>
/dev/sdb1            2048 307201266 307199219 146.5G 83 Linux<br>
/dev/sdb2       307202048 317442047  10240000   4.9G 82 Linux swap /       Solaris<br>
/dev/sdb3  *    317442048 471042047 153600000  73.2G 83 Linux<br>
/dev/sdb4       471042048 481282047  10240000   4.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris<br><br>
```

(sdb is my external hard drive)

Do I need to reinstall Kali a certain way? I've tried a couple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output it appears that you only have Windows installed on your first Hard Drive (/dev/sda).  You have most likely selected that as your default boot drive.  Windows can't read a Linux partition, so its boot manager can't boot to a Linux install.

On the other hand, the default Ubuntu boot manager, Grub, can boot to either Linux or Windows.  If you installed Grub on your primary drive when you boot to your first drive you would have the option of all the OSes in your Boot menu.

You could alternatively select your second drive as your default boot drive.  Update your grub boot manager on that drive and it will scan all your attached drives and add all installed OSes to the boot menu.  The command to update the grub boot manager is:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Now when you have that drive selected via your bio drive boot order as the default boot drive you will have all your OS installs (all the Windows and all the Linux installs) listed as options in your boot menu.

I see two Linux install in your output.  They are:

```
/dev/sdb1 - a 146G partition
/dev/sdb3 - a  73G partition
```

You could attach any number of drives (external or internal) and install other Linux OSes to it.  The install will install (update) the default grub boot manager and have all your OS installs including the new one in the boot menu.

You could use a disk partition editor such as `gparted` to rearange your partitions `(resize, move, or create)` so that you can have a partition of a new OS install on one of the current drives you have `(/dev/sda or dev/sdb)`.  After you have a partition for your install, just run the live Ubuntu disk and install any additional Linux version you with to have included in your boot menu.

Comment: I see typos in my answer and a mistake that will be corrected.  It won't change the answer, just clarify it.  Thanks for accepting the answer.  I'll correct the answer within the hour.